# Using jqGrid userdata

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid on an ASP.Net MVC view. I want to use to pass the value of a hidden text control on the page as an additional parameter to a jqGrid method.

I have the following hidden text field:

```
<div>
<%= Html.Hidden("contactId", Model.ContactId) %>
</div>
```

and I want to do something like:

```
userdata: {contactId : jQuery('#contactId')}
```

in the jqGrid call. The Controller Action method has the following signature:

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, object userdata)
```

But when I run it, `userdata` in the C# code just says `System.Object` when I inspect it in the debugger, and I don't think I can get anythings useful out of it.

Any ideas where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jqGrid property you want is postData. UserData goes the other way.

Change your call to JqGrid to include:

```
postData: {contactId : jQuery('#contactId').val()}
```

Then change the signature of your action to take a contactId:

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, 
    int contactId)
```

I guessed at the type. Use the real type in place of int.

Comment: contactId is a Guid encoded into a string, when I have string contactId in the signature I get the following string value : "[object HTMLInputElement]".
I presume I need to get the value of the jQuery('#contactId') element rather than the element itself. Unfortunately I am completely new to jQuery/JavaScript and don't know how to do that!

Comment: Got it! Need to have postData: {contactId : jQuery('#contactId').val()} to get the string representation of the Guid. Many thanks.

Comment: You can change string -> Guid and MVC binding will convert it for you.